# Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Quaternion'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a 2D game, but I need to be able to shoot in the direction of the mouse, so I am trying to set the rotation of an empty to point towards the mouse so that the projectile can shoot from the empty because I don't want the character to rotate, but I get an error on the last line "Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Quaternion'" How do I fix this? I can't use a Rigidbody 2D because the empty is parented and inside of a player with a RidgidBody2D and collider. If there is a better way to do this (which there probably is), let me know.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Point_and_Shoot : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera cam;
    public Rigidbody2D rb; //Ridgidbody of player
    public Transform rb2; //Transform of empty (empty is at same position as player but it's parented so I have to take position from player because the position is relative to the parent)
    Vector2 mousePos;

    void Update()
    {
        mousePos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector2 lookDir = mousePos - rb.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDir.y, lookDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
        rb2.rotation = angle; //<-- The error is here
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is rather clear. `rb2.rotation` is of type `Quaternion`, where your `angle` variable is of type `float`. You can not assign a `float` to a `Quaternion`. A `Quaternion` in a very simple context is 4 floats representing rotation in 3D space using (x,y,z,w). You need to assign a `Quaternion` to a `Quaternion`, not a `float`. To give a little more help than pointing out the issue, [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/585035/lookat-2d-equivalent-.html) is a thread that should answer your question.

Comment: You are setting the value of type quaternion to a float. In other words, you have just tried to set the rotation to a single value, and it needs 3.

Answer (score 1):

Quaternion represents the rotation for the whole object, not just an angle.
Try to set eulerAngles directly, since it accepts angles as floats (Vector3).
If you want to have a 90° rotation around the Z axis, it would look something like this:

```
eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 90); // Create/set euler angles in degrees.

quaternion.eulerAngles = eulerAngles; // Apply set euler angles to our quaternion

transform.rotation = quaternion; // Apply quaternion to our game object/transform
```

If you want to create some kind of continuous (rotation) motion, you should keep Time.Delta time in mind as a factor.

Answer (score 0):

something like this would work

```cs
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(1, 2) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
    rb2.rotation = new Quaternion(angle, 0, 0, 0);
```

Instead of setting the rotation to a single value, you can use the constructor `Quaternion`. You enter four values. The first three being the x, y, and z. The fourth isn’t needed in this case. **Only type Quaternion works here**. You can’t use Vector3, or Vector2. You can move the angle variable to y or z places because you might not want to rotate the way it was written above. [A link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-ctor.html)

read up on the type system

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/

this is a good explination

Comment: That didn't work, but I ended up fixing it by creating a quaternion in a seperate line with Quaternion.Euler(0,0,axis) and refrencing that. For anyone with the same issue, just look at this example in the unity documentation: Quaternion target = Quaternion.Euler(tiltAroundX, 0, tiltAroundZ); from this page https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html

Answer (score 0):

Your "angle" variable is of a float data type. This cannot be assigned to Quaternion, as Quaternion calls for 4 values (float is just assigning 1). Alternatively, you could do this:

```
public Quaternion rb2.rotation;
```

and then assign the angle into quaternion in the form (angle, value, value, value)